# How to send string parameter to url with path?

Tags: python, django, string, url

I want to send a string as parameter to one of my URL in urls.py in Django. The url is 
path('competitions//about', views.comp_about, name='comp_about'),

Im sending my string through my HTML file as

```
   <a href="% url 'comp_about' {{c.comp_name}}%">Register Now!</a>
```

where c is my object with data member comp_name

this is final url after clicking
http://127.0.0.1:8000/competitions/%%20url%20'comp_about'%20Comp1%

It says Page not found!

Ive searched SO and google for problem why I am facing.

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def comp_about(request,comp_name):
comps= Competition.objects.get(comp_name=comp_name)
context={
   "comps": comps
}
return render(request,"competition/about.html",context)
```

html File

```
<h4>List of Comps</h4>
<br>
<div class="section">
    {% if comps %}
    <ul>   
    {% for c in comps%}
         <li>
            {{c.comp_name}} <br> <a href="% url 'comp_about'       {{c.comp_name}}%">Register Now!</a>
         </li>
         <br><Br>
    {% endfor %}

    {% endif%}
</ul>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
path('competitions/<comp_name>/about', views.comp_about, name='comp_about'),
```

models.py

```
class Competition(models.Model):
comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
comp_description = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
comp_team_size = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
comp_payment_fee = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
comp_rules = models.TextField(max_length=10000,blank=False)
comp_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=False)
comp_registration_deadline = models.DateField(null=True,blank=False)
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-id']

def __str__(self):
    return self.comp_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something that looks like the following.  You can read more about the syntax and what you can do [in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url).  Note that in your OP, you were missing the opening and closing braces `{` and `}` needed around a django template filter.  Make sure you include them.

```
<a href="{% url 'comp_about' comp_name=c.comp_name%}">Register Now!</a>
```